# Finding general solution to differential equation $y-3y^{7}=(y^{3}+6x)y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have a question where I need to find the general solution of the differential equation $y-3y^{7}=(y^{3}+6x)y'$, where the solution is in the form $F(x,y)=C$. I am only concerned about finding $F(x,y)$, and I have been advised to rewrite this equation in differential form, but I am still unsure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated with this problem!

Comment: you must compute a integrating factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d\mu(y)}{dy}(-3y^7+y)(-21y^6+1)\mu(y)=-6\mu(y)$$
$$\frac{\frac{\partial \mu(y)}{\partial y}}{\mu(y)}=-\frac{7}{y}$$
$$\mu(y)=\frac{1}{y^7}$$
and then we have
$$-3+\frac{1}{y(x)^6}-\frac{(6x+y(x)^3)y'(x)}{y(x)^7}=0$$
and let $$P(x,y)=\frac{1}{y^6}-3,Q(x,y)=-\frac{6x+y^3}{y^7}$$ and we get
$$\frac{\partial P(x,y}{\partial y}=-\frac{6}{y^7}=\frac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}$$
and the solution is given by $$f(x,y)=C_1$$ where $C_1$ is a arbitrary constant

Comment: Would I then just multiply $y-3y^{7}=(y^{3}+6x)y'$ with the integrating factor $\frac{1}{y^{7}}$ ?

Comment: yes this would i do

Comment: So in this case, once we apply the integrating factor, we can then treat it like an exact differential?

Comment: @Dr Can you please explain to me your method of solution!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write it in terms of $x'(y)$. You will see its a linear differential equation!

$$\frac{dx}{dy} + \frac{6x}{y-3y^7} = \frac{y^3}{y-3y^7}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write $(y-3y^7)dx-(y^3+6x)dy=0$ then
$$p(y)=\dfrac{M_y-N_x}{-M}=\dfrac{7}{-y}$$
then 
$$I=e^{\int p(y)dy}=\dfrac{1}{y^7}$$
is integrating factor.